# Download youtube playlist to ogg

Tags: youtube, mp3, youtube-dl

how can I download a playlist to ogg?

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <url to playlist>
```

I'm trying:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format ogg <url to playlist>
```

Error:

`youtube-dl: error: invalid audio format specified`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, use `vorbis` instead of ogg in your command

Comment: Since ogg is a container for both Vorbis and Opus, do you know what will happen when I download an audio only (DASH) .opus file, together with the parameter `--audio-format vorbis`? I can see that the resulting file is a .ogg file, but is the .opus file being transcoded to Vorbis, or is it only being embedded as is in the resulting ogg container?